# Can shell_exec run my machine learning code ? It runs fine on terminal but returns NULL in shell_exec

Tags: php, python, machine-learning, shell-exec

I have a python script which is running neural networks based on keras, it runs fine but when i use to run that script through shell_exec in my php and use var_dump i get "NULL".

I have already seen many solutions. I have increased max_execution_time and max_input time in php.ini to 5000. I am also giving full paths of files and required environment in command. Also i have given all permissions to folders (lampp, htdocs, (my php file folder)) This is the command which gets finally called in shell_exec.

```
source /home/characterleveldl/anaconda3/bin/activate /home/characterleveldl/anaconda3/envs/spyderr && python fyp_final.py 5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/charlevel_fyp/train.csv /opt/lampp/htdocs/charlevel_fyp/test.csv 86save_true.pdf 86save_random.pdf 86save_result.txt 2>&1
```

fyp_final.py , train.csv, test.csv everything exists in same folder as the php file. I ran the same exact command via terminal in root mode and it ran without any error. But in below php code it returns NULL.

```
$cmd_initial ='source /home/characterleveldl/anaconda3/bin/activate /home/characterleveldl/anaconda3/envs/spyderr && ';

$cmd = $cmd_initial . 'python fyp_final.py ' . $num_classes . ' ' . $train . ' ' . $test . ' ' . $save_true . ' ' . $save_random . ' ' . $save_text . ' 2>&1'; 
$command = escapeshellcmd($cmd);
$output = shell_exec($command);
var_dump($cmd);
var_dump($output);
```

Please help me. If i am doing something wrong or is it even possible to run machine learning code from php since i tried running small codes they run perfectly.

Comment: Redirect stderr to stdout with `2>&1` at the end of the command. Then see if there's any error message.

Comment: I already did that see my $cmd valriable at the end there is 2>&1. Still i get NULL

Comment: I still have same problem. Can anybody help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I solved it via putting my code inside a shell script and then executing this script via `shell_exec`. It now works fine.